# How to copy website design to inject it in a node.js project?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I need to write a program (in node.js) using the design of an existing website. So far, my program in node.js is the following : (it's normal to be that simple at this step since I'm ony interesting on the design code and how I can inject it in an embedded javascript page).

Comment: "Inject"? You need the html,  css, image assets, page js, etc. Do you mean you want to make a request to the page you're copying and put the result on your page? That is still fraught with gotchas.

Comment: You'd be better off using an iFrame, although it's not clear what you mean by "play with that in my program". Again: you'd need all the CSS, assets, JavaScript, etc. in order for anything to actually work, or even display correctly. I'm not sure where the disconnect is here.